# Achieve an inner text-shadow for thinner looking fonts

Tags: css

I've seen other solutions on this topic, but none of them did the result I need (or want).

The problem is, Mac renders some fonts in an awkward way, the fonts are way too thick, even on Regular style. It's annoying!

So I thought I'd go for a CSS-Workaround to let the fonts seem thinner. All I could think of would be an inner-shadow for texts in hope they won't get too blurred, but this is easier said than done, text-shadow doesn't support this (for whatever reason).

Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be a losing battle, if you take into consideration that now, rather than the possibility of only dealing with fonts at a fixed resolution (72dpi, the standard on monitors for a decade or so, now), you also have to deal with some Mac's "retina displays" where the resolution is approximately 220-227ppi.

I'm also certain I read somewhere that those programs that have not been rewritten to scale properly on retina displays have to be interpolated by the OS, so it's quite possible that, from Mac to Mac, browser to browser, the same font is going to look quite different. As of right now, the only browsers I can confirm having Retina support are Safari (big surprise there, right?) and Chrome.

(For more information on this subject, see this question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54905/retina-macbook-pro-fonts-look-terrible)

You might be able to vary the fonts used based on pixel-ratio with a media query, if you are really committed to trying to hit this moving target.

```
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    /* all your retina-display-tweaked settings, here */
}
```

Comment: To add: I've run into many a headache from different rendering of fonts even on different browsers on same-generation Macs (or, conversely, the same browser on different platforms). "Losing battle," in my experience, is an understatement.

Comment: Biggest differences you'll find are between Firefox and IE browsers, or even Firefox on Mac vs Firefox on Win, due to the sporadic support for ClearType, which was Microsoft's attempt to create font-smoothing algorithms in their own proprietary format, if I recall correctly. This is just one of the reasons I gave up, long ago, on having complete pixel-by-pixel control over anything web-based. It just can't be done on sane budgets.

Comment: @mori57: Thanks for your answer, I guess you're right about this, I've been checking 3 different Apple devices and the font looked different every time: First was a G4 Powerbook with a low resolution - it had the worst font-rendering on both, Firefox and Safari, then I tried a Mac Mini at a monitor with slightly higher resolution. It was looking a lot better, even though OSX and browser versions were identical. So I guess the PPI really matter here. Last device was an iPad 3, where it was looking the best, of course. I guess I'Ve to give up here, but thanks for helping!

Comment: Sadly, typography still suffers a lot on the web, and mainly due to the fact that there are millions of different devices in use at any particular time, all of which feature different support for font-rendering. I'd advise against trying to find thin fonts, mainly for legibility, as user-based resizing will have an even greater adverse effect on the text... due to proportions, any decreases in height will scale the vertical strength of the line down faster than horizontal... ie. the shorter it gets, the faster you run out of pixels to indicate the vertical lines.

Comment: That aside, have you looked at any of the webfonts available through places like Google Fonts? You might be able to find a font that renders well enough on most browsers (since the glyphs will be served identically to all browsers that support webfonts), and most of them are intentionally designed to try to accomodate web-based rendering. http://www.google.com/webfonts are free, but there are others out there that vary from free to pay-per-site. Good luck!

Comment: @mori75: Actually I've used one of them while noticing the problem: Patua One - http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patua+One - looks pretty different, you'd almost assume that it uses faux bold at some devices, because the difference is that visible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a little bit too much effect but i think this is what your are looking for.

Adding a text inner shadow effect with :before & :after

```
.depth:before, .depth:after {
content: attr(title);
padding: 50px;
color: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
position: absolute;
}

.depth:before { top: 3px; left: 3px }
.depth:after  { top: 4px; left: 4px }​
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4GAkK/

Comment: That's one of the solutions I've tried out before, but I couldn'T really get the result I'd need: thinner looking black text on white background.